# How do I delete files from a message in Discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm trying to program a Tic Tac Toe command for my bot. So I made myself a basic 3x3 grid where the bot adds the O's and X's into the fields by using the node module Canvas. Then it transforms the canvas into a Discord message attachment by using Discord's MessageAttachment constructor: 
`const tictactoeImage = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(),'TicTacToe.png');` 
Afer that, it adds the image to an embed: 
`const tictactoeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setImage('attachment://TicTacToe.png');`

It also adds a SelectMenu with all empty fields to the message, so the user can pick which field they want to set.

And last but not least, it sends the embed, the image and the component to the channel the command was executed in:

```
return message.channel.send({
    embeds: [tictactoeEmbed],
    files: [tictactoeImage],
    components: [gamemessagecomponent],
});
```

For every SelectMenuInteraction (when a user chooses an empty field in the SelectMenu), this process gets repeated and the message gets edited. And there's the problem: Every time I add a new image to the message, it just won't show the new image. The embed still shows the old image.

I tried adding a random integer to the filename, which fixed the issue. Now the embed shows the correct image. But now another problem appeared: All old images are shown above the embed.

Screenshot: https://data.maryubot.xyz/media/tictactoe-issue.png

Apparently, every time I edit the message, new images are being **added** instead of being **overwritten**. This is not the case for embeds or message components. To confirm this, I edited the message the bot sent before like this:

```
return gamemessage.edit({
    content: 'Does this work?',
    embeds: [],
    files: [],
    components: [],
});
```

The embed and the component were gone, but the image(s) were still visible.
My question is: How do I get rid of the old images, so that only the newest image will be visible? (One image at a time) 
I'm trying to avoid creating a new message for each time a user selects a field. 
Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

I used a plugin for Chrome called: Copy as Python Request

It works together with the DevTools in Chrome and after you send a Post, you can see what it would have been if you send it from Requests in Python.

The solution for deleting an attached Image from a Message in Discord without deleting the Message itself it his:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.patch(
    "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/*channelID*/messages/*messageID*",
    json={"attachments":[]},
    headers={"authorization": "*authToken*"}
    )
```